# The secret to crispy sourdough waffles?

Tags: baking, sourdough, waffle

This is my first post so forgive me if I break etiquette! I am trying to figure out why I can't seem to achieve crispy waffles. I've been working with the King Arthur recipe: https://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/classic-sourdough-waffles-or-pancakes-recipe
And I've also tried: https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/246917/sams-sourdough-waffles/
These are pretty different recipes. I preferred the King Arthur in terms of flavor, but they both just came out... soft. Could it be the recipe, or the waffle iron (mine is old and cheap), or maybe the process? Ideas?

Comment: Do you get crispy regular waffles with the maker that you have? If so, it's not a problem with the device as such. Also, not an answer by any means, but by experimentation I have found that a couple of tablespoons of cornstarch/cornflour in the batter can enhance the crispiness of a waffle

Answer (score 3):

We regularly use the King Arthur Flour recipe, and consistently get waffles that are crispy on the outside, soft on the inside. A couple suggestions:

- Make sure the waffle iron is completely preheated before adding the batter.
- This recipe does need the waffles to cook for long enough; they'll be slightly dark. If you're only cooking them to a light golden, they aren't done enough.
- Don't stack the waffles between cooking and serving, or the steam will make them soggy - put them in a single layer, and if you can't serve them immediately put them in a very low oven while you're making the rest of the waffles.